# Grails controller not getting current value of a dropdown in a controller

Tags: grails, user-interface, groovy

I have a `dropdown (g:select)` in my view that displays a list from a domain class. I want to println whatever value that is in it whenever a save button is clicked. Below is the script in the view

```
<g:select params="[tablename: storehouseInstance?.tablename]" name="tablename"     from="${Warehouse.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="${Warehouse.list()}" value="tablename"
noSelection="['':'Choose Table']"
onchange="${remoteFunction (
controller: 'warehouse',
action: 'updateSelect',
params:  "'warehouse.id=' + this.value + storehouseInstance?.tablename" ,
param: "this.value",
update: [success:'fieldSelection'] //update: 'fieldselection'
)}"/>
```

And in my controller i have:

```
def save() {

        println("params are "+ params)
       println("Saving table name: " + params.tablename)
}
```

I am getting tablename to be '1' instead of the value that should be something like 'MYTESTVALUE'

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the warehouse's name property is `name`, try this instead:

```
<g:select params="[tablename: storehouseInstance?.tablename]" 
    name="tablename"     
    from="${Warehouse.list()}" 
    optionKey="name"     // I changed this line
    optionValue="name"   // I changed this line too
    value="tablename"
    noSelection="['':'Choose Table']"
    onchange="${remoteFunction (
        controller: 'warehouse',
        action: 'updateSelect',
        params:  "'warehouse.id=' + this.value + storehouseInstance?.tablename" ,
        param: "this.value",
        update: [success:'fieldSelection']
)}"/>
```

In a `g:select` the parameter that is sent to the server is defined by `optionKey` and the value that is displayed in the dropdown is defined by `optionValue`

### Aside

From an MVC purity point-of-view, you shouldn't be doing queries in GSPs, e.g. `Warehouse.list()`. Instead you should retrieve the data you need in a service/contoller and pass it via the model to the view (GSP).